# Can i do this on return to handle Exception

Tags: c#, datatable, return, try-catch

in my function i am returning a datatable that is returned by method

`MyDatatable(sqlQuery, connection ),`

but it may generate some exceptions that will threw error can i do something like this

```
return  try {cmn.MyDatatable(qry, con)} catch(Exception ex){null};
```

i don't want to do  this way

```
DataTable dt =null;
try{
dt = cmn.MyDatatable(qry, con);
}catch().....
return dt==null ? null :dt;
```

Comment: Why not do the magic within `MyDatatable` if it fail the method gotta return null rite ?

Comment: you're absolutely right my friend but dont you think that if no data will be fetched then it will also return null 
how i will handle it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is quite wrong. You can do it this way:

```
try
{
    return cmd.MyDatatable(qry, con);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    return null;
}
```

Although I doubt you want to swallow *all* exceptions.

Comment: I'm sorry, you can't have a one-liner.

Comment: @Photon Just in case you'll use PHP in future, it has one liner: `return @cmd.MyDataTable(qry, con)`. It swallows all exception though, so that's akin to `try { return method(); } catch { return null; }`

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the best way is to do that :

```
{
  object l_oOutDatatable = null;
  try
  {
    oOutDatable = cmd.MyDatatable(qry, con);
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    log.Message(e.ToString);
  }

  return l_oOutDatatable;
}
```

You must ALWAYS manage exception, because they must have a good reason to be thrown ;). More over it's consider as a good practice to have a single return in each method.

And in bonus, you can use the `??` keyword : This keyword is meaning to return the value or something else if it's null. as Example : `c = a ?? b` is similar to this : `c = (a!=null) ? a : b;`

Comment: I might just be me, but i have some problems seeing a empty catch block and the word best in the same context.

Comment: Thats not best practice to leave an empty catch, you should do something with the exception, log it, return it.

Comment: Yes, i updated :) But i just wanted to emphasis the syntax option.

Comment: I usually log it and allow few try before throw an exception wich manage errors. Like trying 3 times to connect and stuff like that.

Answer (score 1):

You should return the exception all the way to the client which is calling this code. It is up to the client to handle the exception.

Remember you should only be catching exceptions where you expect them to occur, such as trying to connect to a db or write a file to disk etc.

You should also make your exception catches as specific as possible to catch a know exception that normally occurs when you get the dataset.

```
try
{
    return cmd.MyDatatable(qry, con);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //Log exeption
    Throw ex
}
```

If this is just a check to handle null datatables when they have no results then you should test if they are null or populated. This would be a better solution if it is part of your applications ability to return empty datatables.

```
var dataTableResult = cmd.MyDatatable(qry, con);
if ( dataTableResult != null)
{
    return dataTableResult;
}

return null;
```

Comment: Use an empty `throw` to rethrow an exception in C#. `throw ex` is how you do it in Java.

Comment: @zmbq throw ex will re-throw the handled exception. you can use throw if you have a parameterless catch block in c#

Comment: throw works in any block. throw ex will overwrite the stacktrace in ex.